# How to set the current user in cell? Swift, Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, cell, pfuser

Day, guys. Help me.I can not solve the problem for three days

I make an app look like an Instagram. I want to make sure that when you create a post, in cell of tableview,  writing his nickname.

I am try this:

```
findSweeter.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in
        if error == nil{
            let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject  as PFUser!
            cell1.usernamelabel.text = user.username
        }
    }
}
```

But thats issue: [AnyObject]? is not convertible to 'NSArray' & 'NSArray is not convertible to PFUser'

Help, pls. im using Parse.com

Comment: You can't convert an array to a PFUser - the array contains PFUsers  - `let user=objects[0] as! PFUser`

Comment: @Paulw11 so what i must to do?

Comment: I showed you how to get the PFUser

Comment: @Paulw11 here's an issue to: Cannot subscript a value of type [AnyObject]? with an index of type 'Int'

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem so easly. I just changed PFUser variable in Data on Parse Clotd to String:

`cell1.usernamelabel.text = sweet.objectForKey("usa") as? String`

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the cast, but the fact that `objects` is an optional array: `[AnyObject]?`

You have to unwrap the array first:

```
findSweeter.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in
    if error == nil && indexPath.row < objects?.count{
       var user: PFUser
       if let userObject = objects?[indexPath.row] {
          user = userObject as! PFUser
          cell1.usernamelabel.text = user.username
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: this one error here: Could bot find an overoad for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: >if let userObject = objects?[index] //here

Comment: Did you change "index" to the index you want ?

Comment: oh no, thats was stupid mistake. So, build has been completed, but  fatal error: Array index out of range

Comment: i am changed index to indexPath.row

Comment: Which index did you put ? Try with "0"

Comment: Add a `println("Object array size : \(objects?.count)")` to check if you have object in your array. (Before the crash obviously)

Comment: where i must add this line?

Comment: Before this one `var user: PFUser`

Comment: Object array size : Optional(0)

Comment: Ok so basically your problem is solved. For this question I mean. But know you have to find out why your objects array is empty. I've never worked with Parse. So i can't help you. But once you find out why it is empty the code I gave you will work.

Comment: However to prevent any crash you can complete the condition `if error == nil` by `if error == nil && indexPath.row < objects?.count`