# "[AnyObject]? is not convertible to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

Here I am with another question.

As I was coding through my app, I'm using Parse Framework, and I'm using a query to obtain the username off the database:

```
var showUsername:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    //showUsername.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("user")!.objectId)

    showUsername.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("user")!)

    showUsername.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

         if error == nil{
            let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray!).lastObject as! PFUser
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username
        }

    }
```

I am having trouble with this two lines of code:

```
//showUsername.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("user")!.objectId)
```

this one I have it commented out because it says that with the .objectID is wrong, so if I take that out, it says it's fine. So I was wondering if the function of it would be the same???

And also, this line :

```
let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray!).lastObject as! PFUser
```

It shows on Xcode that is correct, but when I run the app, it freezes and crashed because of that line of code due to the error that says that "[AnyObject]? is not convertible to 'NSArray'

any ways to work around this?

I already tried what this other links say:

"['[AnyObject]?' is not convertible to 'NSArray'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421211/anyobject-is-not-convertible-to-nsarray)"

"[How to set the current user in cell? Swift, Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876944/how-to-set-the-current-user-in-cell-swift-parse)"

And I get no errors in my code, and it runs, but the username is not changed to the actual username, it still says "Label"

unless it has to do with the query missing the .objectID?

Comment: Try `(objects as NSArray?)?.lastObject as! PFUser`. Anyway, Swift arrays also have a last property. So you could use `let user:PFUser? = objects.last as? PFUser`

Comment: When I try that, it says "Cast from '[AnyObject]?' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question (the line you commented out):

In `showUsername.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("user")!.objectId)`

unwrap the objectId by adding an ! as follows

`showUsername.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("user")!.objectId!)`

The second part of your question:

Replace

```
let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray!).lastObject as! PFUser
```

by

```
let user = (objects as! [PFUser]).last
```

Comment: This did it!
After trying this it showed the username on the post! Thank you (:

Comment: Probably more Swift-y to use this: `let user = (objects as? [PFUser])?.last` That way the app won't crash when `objects == nil`.

Comment: @nielsbot I agree with you from the perspective of safety. When studying the docs and examples from Parse.com I concluded that in case error == nil objects can never be nil, so I considered it safe to unwrap it immediately. But rethinking I do prefer your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(objects as? NSArray)?.lastObject as! PFUser
```

Looks like *objects* is an optional array of AnyObject. You can cast it to an optional NSArray.

Anyway, Swift arrays also have a last property. You could use

```
`let user:PFUser? = objects.last as? PFUser`
```

instead. Your inner condition code can be written as

```
let user = objects?.last as? PFUser
cell.usernameLabel.text = user?.username ?? ""
```

Some explanation:

*User* is an optional PFUser, a PFUser reference that is a PFUser instance or nothing. The type is *Optional*. (Which can also be written *PFUser?*).

`objects?.last` evaluates to `objects.last` when *objects* ≠ *nil* and *nil* otherwise.

Now *user* refers to the last *PFUser* instance in *objects* or nothing (*nil*).

`user?.username` evaluates to `user.username` when *user* ≠ *nil* and *nil* otherwise.

Finally the `??` operator returns the left-hand expression if it is non-nil, and the right hand side if it is. I.e. if the username is *nil*, use the empty string instead (*""*)

Comment: okay this one kinda worked. It displays "username" if I type "username" in the quotes. Now I just gotta figure out how to get the usernames there

Comment: I added some explanation